# Does accessing the database from ViewModel violate the MVC principle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I am writing an application in MVC2 using Entity Framework

As I know ViewModel has to contain only data without any logic to database. Suppose I have `Product` class that is ADO.NET entity that has `EntityCollection<ProductToStatus>` when `ProductToStatus` is many-to-many table. I have `ProductModel` (that takes `Product` in its .ctor) which is passed to `View`.

```
public class ProductModel
{
    ....
    public Product Item {get; private set;}
    ...
    public ProductModel(Product item)
    {
         ...
         this.Item = item;
         ...
    }
}
```

In `View` I need to render all statuses of the product, so to do it I need to query the DB by `item.ProductToStatus.Select(s=>s.ProductStatus).ToList();` in the `ProductModel`, but this sends request to the DB and thus does it violates the MVC principle?

Is this OK or I need to do something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you shouldn't do this.  Your controller should collect the data required for your view and should package it up and pass it to the view for it to render.

So your `ProductModel` should either take the details of the `Product` it needs in its constructor or through properties (my preference) or should, at a push, use the `Product` it is given to do all the querying in the constructor to set all of its internal fields but not keep a reference to the `Product` around.  I don't like the using the `Product` in the constructor particularly as its doing work in the constructor which is not great, but depending on what it is doing exactly it might be ok.

Its probably better to make your `ProductModel` have a load of properties, then you can create it like so:

```
var model = new ProductModel()
   {
       Statuses=product.ProductToStatus.Select(s=>s.ProductStatus).ToList(),
       Name=product.Name,
       OtherProperty=GetPropertyValue(product),
       //etc
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its violating the pattern. You should fill your ViewModel in the Controller and then pass it to your view.

Off course it will work, but thats not the idea of model-view-controller.